# Ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Приложение не запускается и выдает ошибку java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(java.lang.String, java.util.UUID)' on a null object reference

ServerThread.class:

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothServerSocket;
    private final CommunicatorService communicatorService;

    public ServerThread(CommunicatorService communicatorService) {
        this.communicatorService = communicatorService;
        final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("BluetoothApp", UUID.fromString(MainActivity.UUID));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ServerThread", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        bluetoothServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {

        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        Log.d("ServerThread", "Started");

        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("ServerThread", "Stop: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                break;
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                communicatorService.createCommunicatorThread(socket).startCommunication();
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            bluetoothServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ServerThread", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public final static String UUID = "19820c90-fd4a-11e7-8f1a-0800200c9a66";

    private class WriteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                clientThread.getCommunicator().write(args[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private BroadcastReceiver discoverDevicesReceiver;
    private BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishedReceiver;

    private final List<BluetoothDevice> discoveredDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> listAdapter;

    private TextView textData;
    private EditText textMessage;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private ServerThread serverThread;

    private ClientThread clientThread;

    private final CommunicatorService communicatorService = new CommunicatorService() {
        @Override
        public Communicator createCommunicatorThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            return new CommunicatorImpl(socket, new CommunicatorImpl.CommunicationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(final String message) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textData.setText(textData.getText().toString() + "\n" + message);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        textData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_text);
        textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_text);

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, discoveredDevices) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                final BluetoothDevice device = getItem(position);
                ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(device.getName());
                return view;
            }
        };
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

    public void makeDiscoverable(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        i.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void discoverDevices(View view) {

        discoveredDevices.clear();
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (discoverDevicesReceiver == null) {
            discoverDevicesReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();

                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                        if (!discoveredDevices.contains(device)) {
                            discoveredDevices.add(device);
                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        if (discoveryFinishedReceiver == null) {
            discoveryFinishedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    getListView().setEnabled(true);
                    if (progressDialog != null)
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Поиск закончен. Выберите устройство для отправки ообщения.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    unregisterReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver);
                }
            };
        }

        registerReceiver(discoverDevicesReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        registerReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));

        getListView().setEnabled(false);

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Поиск устройств", "Подождите...");

        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        if (discoverDevicesReceiver != null) {
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(discoverDevicesReceiver);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Не удалось отключить ресивер " + discoverDevicesReceiver);
            }
        }

        if (clientThread != null) {
            clientThread.cancel();
        }
        if (serverThread != null) serverThread.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        serverThread = new ServerThread(communicatorService);
        serverThread.start();

        discoveredDevices.clear();
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
        if (clientThread != null) {
            clientThread.cancel();
        }

        BluetoothDevice deviceSelected = discoveredDevices.get(position);

        clientThread = new ClientThread(deviceSelected, communicatorService);
        clientThread.start();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Вы подключились к устройству \"" + discoveredDevices.get(position).getName() + "\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        if (clientThread != null) {
            new WriteTask().execute(textMessage.getText().toString());
            textMessage.setText("");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Сначала выберите клиента", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: а вы на реальном ус-ве пробовали? Вроде в эмуляторе нет блютуза. Пермишены есть?

Comment: Likhanov, на реальном устройстве с bluetooth заработало

Comment: я оставил ответ, на будущее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за тестирования `Bluetooth` на эмуляторе.

Эмулятор не поддерживает `Bluetooth`.

Также к ограничениям эмулятора относится

- невозможность осуществлять реальные телефонные звонки (только имитация)
- вставка / извлечение SD-карты
- USB
- наушники, подключенные к устройству
- NFC

Взято из [документации](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#starting)

Конкретно `Bluetooth` можно сымитировать сторонними сервисами, например, с помощью [виртуальной машины](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8004374/9007098)